# Instance label rewrite when __address__ is the same and Prometheus is a sidecar container

Tags: prometheus

I have a setup in AWS Lightsail Containers where Prometheus is loaded as a sidecar container for every app container. So if I have two app containers, I also have two Prometheus containers running. (The Prometheus containers forward metrics using `remote_write` to a global Prometheus instance that's used for querying.)

The Prometheus configuration for every sidecar container looks like this:

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: app
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - localhost:8080
```

Note that the target address is the same for every target.

As I understand it, the `instance` label should be unique for every target (?), but here it's not. How could I use label rewrites to change them to something unique? Do I have e.g. the IP address available as a meta label? I'm not using any service discovery, so e.g. `__meta_lightsail_instance_name` is not available.

Comment: What value do you have for the instance label ? The pod IP ?

Comment: Currently it's the target address from the config above: `localhost:8080`

Comment: An IP address will be the same too: `127.0.0.1`. Am I correct that it is your ambition to keep Prometheus config the same for all instances? Because otherwise the easiest way will be to add some static labels. For example, change `job` or add `external_labels`.

Comment: Yes, the configuration is static, and deployed with `n` app containers as a sidecar. There is no service discovery that I am aware of in Lightsail Containers. I was hoping there was a magic variable I could use to e.g. translate the DNS name to an IP or something, that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using external labels with environment variables in my `prometheus.yml` global config:

```yaml
global:
  external_labels:
    container: ${HOSTNAME}
```

The `${HOSTNAME}` env var is set by ECS Fargate / Lightsail Containers on the container.

For this to work, a feature flag needs to be enabled, called `--enable-feature=expand-external-labels`. My final `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM prom/prometheus
ADD prometheus.yml /etc/prometheus/
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/prometheus"]
CMD ["--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml", \
     "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus", \
     "--storage.tsdb.retention.time=1d", \
     "--enable-feature=expand-external-labels"]
```